# Deployment Nuxt 2 universal (SSR) application on Google Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

[START OF UPDATE 3] ----------------------------
Good News: I have built and deployed web app but have errors:
[image: Errors in Console with Vuetify]

[image: Screenshot of the folder structure].
 1. I have moved all Nuxt project into the src folder.
 2. I have moved the functions folder in prod folder and renamed it as server.
 3. I created a new /prod/user folder.
 4. I created a copy of the nuxt.config.js file and copied it into the /prod/server folder in order to use it /prod/server/index.js file.
 5. I have edited package.js.
 6. I have edited firebase.json file.
 7. And finally I have edited /src/nuxt.config.js file

package.js

```
{
  "name": "ap-test-vue-nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first badass Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "Alex Pilugin",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd prod && cd server && npm install",
    "start": "cd src && npm run dev",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=development firebase serve",
    "build": "cd src && npm run build && cd .. && npm run copystatic && npm run copydist",
    "generate": "cd src && npm run generate",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only hosting,functions",
    "copystatic": "cp -R src/static/ prod/client",
    "copydist": "cp -R prod/server/nuxt/dist/ prod/client/assets",
    "all": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only hosting,functions"
  }
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "prod/server"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "prod/client",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nuxtssr"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
//Error when deploy functions: import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
const colors = require('vuetify/es5/util/colors').default;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  buildDir: "./../prod/server/nuxt",
  ssrLog: true,
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    cache: true,
    extractCSS: true,
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (process.browser) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
      }
    }
  }, ...
```

/prod/server/package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.5",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.11.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

/prod/server/index.js

```
// functions/index.js

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt-start");

const nuxtConfig = require("./nuxt.config.js");

const config = {
  ...nuxtConfig,
  dev: false,
  debug: false,
  buildDir: "nuxt",
  build: {
    publicPath: "/assets/"
  }
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

let isReady = false;

async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  if (!isReady) {
    try {
      isReady = await nuxt.ready();
    } catch (error) {
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
  await nuxt.render(req, res);
}

exports.nuxtssr = functions.https.onRequest(handleRequest);
```

[END OF UPDATE 3] -------------------------------

Nuxt.js version 2 doesn't have **server** folder and after moving all folders into the new **src** folder - I cannot execute `"npm run build"` command... since:

> `nuxt build` command not found!

I try to deploy my first universal (SSR) Nuxt application on the Google Firebase.
I almost finished my Udemy course [Nuxt.js - Vue.js on Streroids](https://www.udemy.com/course/nuxtjs-vuejs-on-steroids/) and now it's time to upload my application on Google Firebase.

I found 2 different approaches how to do it:
1. [dev.to: Deploy nuxt on Firebase](https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8).
2. [dev.to: How to host Nuxt.js application on firebase with a single command](https://dev.to/slushnys/how-to-host-nuxt-js-application-on-firebase-with-a-single-command-1nio)

2nd approach - create a **src** folder and move all project into **src** folder [github.com/slushnys/dealas](https://github.com/slushnys/dealas) and it doesn't use Express.js on serverside (it uses [nuxt-start](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-start)

1st approach - moving only folders into **src** folder , but leaving all main files outside. And in this case we use Express.js on serverside - which I don't want to use at the moment.

I try to implement 1st approach without Express.js (using Nuxt-start library).

```
//package.js
{
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "nuxt",
     "build": "nuxt build",
     "start": "nuxt start",
     "generate": "nuxt generate"
   },
}

//firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "functions/.nuxt",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}

//nuxt.config.js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  //https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8
  srcDir: 'src', //move all folder into the src folder
  buildDir: 'functions/.nuxt', //for firebase-functions
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    },
    extractCSS: true //https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8
  },
```

The issue with scripts in package.js - I cannot find **server** folder in **src** folder:
[image: screenshot of the package.js]

Also I see error when I try to execute `npm run build`:

```
> nuxt build

sh: nuxt: command not found
```

Version of Nuxt: **"nuxt": "^2.0.0"**

I need commands for scripts "dev", "start", "build" to fix my application :(

[image: Screenshot of package.js] 
[image: Screenshot of functions/index.js]
[image: Screenshot of firebase.js]

Comment: Are you going to deploy as a Single page Application?

Comment: Not. I am going to deploy an Universal (SSR - Server Side Rendering) Nuxt Application

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjQsOy-8Wqo

Comment: Thank you, but that youtube video doesn't contain information how to deploy the application!

Comment: Have you sure, you ran npm install?

Comment: yes. I did npm install several times